# Though I have #define X, [Conditional("X")] is preventing the method from running

Tags: c#

I've a web service that has a static Log helper class, that looks like this:

```
#define LOGGING
namespace blah
{
  static class Log{
    class LogFile { ... }

    [Conditional("LOGGING")]
    public static void CreateLogFile(string path) { ... }
  }
} 


//in some other class
void SetupLogger(){
  DateTime dtStart = DateTime.UtcNow;
  Log.CreateLogFile("c:\\temp\\log.log");
  DateTime dtEnd = DateTime.UtcNow;
}
```

I've been seeing a problem where the `CreateLogFile` method is not being called when I single step in the debugger.. In that `SetupLogging()` method above, the debugger jumps straight from the line defining dtStart to the one defining dtEnd. I'm confused by this, as if I put

```
#if LOGGING
  some code here
#else
  other code here
#endif
```

VisualStudio will grey out the `other code here` so VS at least believes that the LOGGING var is being defined and driving code generation, but the behaviour of the `Conditional()` attribute is the opposite..

I don't have any #undef directives anywhere

Is anything blatantly wrong with this setup? Should a static class arranged like this work properly (i.e. `CreateLogFile()` is available to be called) when debugged in a local IIS (not express)?

Comment: Calls to methods marked with `Conditional` are included or not at compile time, so that seems to indicate something isn't right with the build process. Try removing your `#define` statement and adding the "LOGGING" symbol to project -> properties -> build -> Conditional compilation symbols

Comment: It seems like you are calling CreateLogFile() method from another assembly, which has no LOGGING symbol defined.  LOGGING symbol should be defined in the calling assembly.

Comment: @IgorBendrup you should put that as an answer - I #defined LOGGING in my other class (in another .cs file, in another namespace) also and now it's working as expected, thanks.. Clearly I was ignorant of the scope of #define with regard to the Conditional attribute - if you could say a few words in your answer as to what the scope of #define is, it'd be great - I'm not sure if it's "same .cs file", "same namespace" etc

Comment: The scope of a #define is limited to the file in which it appears.  If you want it broader then you have to use the project setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are calling `CreateLogFile()` method from another file, which has no `LOGGING` symbol defined. The scope of the `LOGGING` symbol [is the file where it have been defined](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt3yck0x(v=vs.100).aspx). So, `LOGGING` symbol should be defined in the file, which contains `SetupLogger()` method.

Another way is to define `LOGGING` symbol for a whole assembly by [editing project properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/define-compiler-option). In this case you should setup project properties for the assembly, which contains `SetupLogger()` method.